# Return value after insert satement with ADODB.Connection and MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic, adodb

I have a SQL statement in Classic ASP like the following (I've rewritten this as an example on here)

```
sql = "exec TESTSP 'mytable', @id output"
sql = sql & " select @company = (select id from company where company 'MyCompany')"
sql = sql & " insert into DETAILS (id, company, description)"
sql = sql & " values (@id, @company, 'Testing')"
sql = sql & " select @id as newid"

Conn.Open sConnectopn
set rs = conn.Execute(sql)

Response.Write(rs("newid"))
```

I know none of this is best practice but its already been written and I can't modify the code at this moment in time but I am trying to get the "id" that was issued by the stored procedure.

So I added the last line:

```
sql = sql & " select @id as newid"
```

and was hoping to get this from the recordset.

Is this possible? I get this error each time:

```
ADODB.Recordset error '800a0cc1' 

Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal.
```

Running this in SQL returns one column called "newinc" with one value. So SQL wise this should work.

Answer (score 2):

OK I have just solved this by using SET NOCOUNT ON - looks like although it was executing it was actually returning multiple outputs behind the scenes!

Comment: There's usually 2 or 3 questions on this a day.

Comment: Classic ADO is notorious for returning row count information as record sets, which is why one commonly uses SET NOCOUNT ON.  The alternative is calling the NextRecordset method in your code to skip the noise until you get to the results of the SELECT.